# Git commit some files

Tags: git, version-control

When I do a git status I see a lot of changed files. Normally 10-15.

Now I want to commit 2-3 files from these changed ones and commit.

What’s the easy to do this without using a mouse to copy the full file path from the git status output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`git add -i`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html) - look for the "Interactive mode" section.

It's a command line interface where you can easily select what to add/remove from the index (modified files, new files, deleted, ...). It's really easy to use.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about the interactive mode.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way? Use a git GUI client

*or*

Use tab completion in your shell (you do use a shell with tab completion, right?): `git add <start typing, hit TAB>`